# Why does submitting hidden POST form via jQuery in an LWC not open a new browser tab?

Tags: lightning-web-components, jquery

This JavaScript code works when clicking a button on a web page but not in a Lightning Web Component action on a record detail page:

```
var form = $('<form />', {
    action: tat_loginAs_URL,
    method: 'POST',
    style: 'display: none;',
    target: '_blank'
}).append($('<input />', {
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'username',
    value: result
})).appendTo('body').submit();
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I neither declared nor called the JavaScript function properly. I got it to work as such:

```
  @api invoke() {
    getAppLogin({ accountId: this.recordId })
      .then((result) => {
        if (result === "false") {
          alert(TAT_Access_Denied);
        } else {
          trackAccountAction({
            accountId: this.recordId,
            actionSummary: "logged in as this customer",
          });
          login(result);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (this.custEmail == undefined || this.custEmail == null) {
          this.errors = "Missing Customer Email";
        } else if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
          this.errors = error.body.map((e) => e.message).join(", ");
        } else if (typeof error.body.message === "string") {
          this.errors = error.body.message;
        }
        this.dispatchEvent(
          new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "Trouble logging in as customer",
            message: "Error: " + this.errors,
            variant: "error",
          })
        );
      });
    function login(result) {
      var form = $("<form />", {
        action: tat_loginAs_URL,
        method: "POST",
        style: "display: none;",
        target: "_blank",
      })
        .append(
          $("<input />", {
            type: "hidden",
            name: "username",
            value: result,
          })
        )
        .appendTo("body")
        .submit();
    }
  }
```

Thank you to @sfdcfox for being willing to help.

Answer (score 5):

LWC is a "managed DOM" framework. That means you can't just go about putting DOM elements wherever you like. If you want to use something like jQuery, you can, but you need to use `lwc:dom="manual"` to make it work:

```
<div class="container" lwc:dom="manual">
</div>
```

---

```
var form = $('<form />', {
    action: tat_loginAs_URL,
    method: 'POST',
    style: 'display: none;',
    target: '_blank'
}).append($('<input />', {
    type: 'hidden',
    name: 'username',
    value: result
})).appendTo('.container').submit();
```

You can read more about it in [Use Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library).

Comment: Thank you for that information, Brian. I'm now importing jQuery and changed 'body' to '.container' but I don't have any HTML elements in my LWC's HTML file, so I don't have anywhere to put lwc:dom="manual". Any suggestions?

Comment: @RobAlexander You must add a container. I missed a space so it hid my original HTML that I added. You need to create that container; I showed a div here, but it could be a span or something else that suits your needs.

Comment: I've now added that div and the code is running, verified by console logging. However, the code is not opening a new tab with tat_loginAS_URL. Any ideas?

Comment: @RobAlexander Check your console for Content Security Policy violations. It may be that this form isn't allowed to execute in the current context. Have you tried doing this in webcomponents.dev to see if you get the same problem?

Comment: No CSP violations in console. I have the tat_loginAs_URL value listed as a CSP Trusted Site (and a CORS Allowed Origin, Remote Site, and Trusted URL for Redirect) in Salesforce.

Comment: @RobAlexander Hey, just noticed I missed your last comment. I'm not sure what else to say at this point. It's challenging to get it just right with security; if possible, I'd advise you just write a standard form in your template and submit it normally. jQuery is quite overkill for your task.